# Iterate through pandas columns for countplots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset of 896k rows in this form:

```
Name    SM_Presence   TL_presence   LS_presence    VC    Eligible

Aaron      0              0           0            0       0
John       1              0           1            1       0
Alex       0              1           1            0       0
Steve      0              0           1            0       1
```

I have to make the countplot for all these features..

So, I have done like this:

```
lists = ['SM_Presence','TL_presence','LS_presence','VC','Eligible']
for i in lists:
    sns.countplot(x = i, data = df)
plt.show()
```

It's only printing countplot of first feature ie. SM_presence and not printing other graphs.. Can someone please suggest me on how to print all graphs at once..

Comment: Put `plt.show()` inside the loop

Comment: `g = sns.catplot(kind='count', data= df.iloc[:, 1:].melt(), x='value', col='variable', col_wrap=3)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering separate plot in `for` loop, build a single countplot for the needed columns using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) which allows unpivoting columns from wide to long format. Use `hue` param to distinguish/divide values between `1` and `0`:

```
sns.countplot(data=df.melt(id_vars='Name'), x='variable', hue='value')
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69940227/7758804) already exitsts